# Oracle cant import .dat file to the oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

Here i have installed

```
windows s 2008 64
oracle 64
```

i have create a database by the name of **testdb** and want to import a file of (**databasefile.dat**) to this
database but after running the following:

```
C:\> imp file=databasefile.dat touser=user_one log=20121024_v368_imp.LOG data_only=Y
```

here after typing sys username with password i get the error of the following

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit
Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

IMP-00037: Character set marker unknown
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
```

where i have done the mistake as i can connect to the my created database with sqldeveloper
and can see the talbe inside which are blank now same data as i have want to import which is been exported from same type of oracle with the same database structure

any help will be appreciable regard..

Comment: How did you create that `databasefile.dat` file?

Comment: Yes that file is been created i have it but want to restore a database on my oracle the database is there i can login to it trough the sqldeveloper and see it's tables....

Comment: @WelcomeAlways - We understand that the file exists.  The question is how it was created.  `imp` is used to import dump files created via the `exp` command.  My guess is that this is not how you created `databasefile.dat`.  My guess is that the file was a data file that was part of a tablespace in some other database.  If so, you can't simply move a data file from one database to another.  You may be able to use a transportable tablespace but that would require that the source database was runnnig.  Are you trying to restore a database backup?  If so, how was the backup created?

Comment: Yes, but now i got the .dmp file
>>imp file=c:\TEMP\ATT2NY8G\5_test_11Apr2013.dmp log=c:\TEMP\ATT2NY8G\5_test_11Apr2013_exp.log data_only=Y 
..........here i want to restore it to the testdb...can you please let me know what else should i add to my code

Comment: @WelcomeAlways - What is the new error that you get when you try to import the new file?  What was the command used to create the dump file (is this a full export?  A tablespace-level export?  A schema-level export?  An object-level export?)

Comment: c:\>imp file=test_11Apr2013.dmp touser=db_owner log=test_11Apr2013_exp.LOG data_only=Y...........this is the command

Comment: this is the result.......
import done in WE8MSWIN1252 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
export client uses US7ASCII character set (possible charset conversion)
IMP-00031: Must specify FULL=Y or provide FROMUSER/TOUSER or TABLES arguments
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully

Comment: @WelcomeAlways - That's the command you're using to import the dump file.  What was the command you used to generate the dump file?  What type of export do you have?  The new error message implies that you may have done a full export in which case you would need to do a full import.  Or you may be trying to import the objects into a different schema from the one you exported them from which would require the `FROMUSER` and `TOUSER` clauses.  This is why we want to know how the file was created.

Comment: here i don't know what command has other part used to export this file but i got a file with the file.dat which i change it to .zip i see to file inside it one .log and .dmp now i want to import it to sinlge database which i create with the database configuration asistant... so i get the uper error during my import...

Comment: please extract you zip and try to import .dmp file. Also you can share .log file with us, to help you.